# Send different notification to the phone and the android wear

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I have an application that send a notifications to smartphones, this notifications are customized with its own layout. I want know if it is possible send a custom notificacion to smartphone and adapted notification to wear. Any idea?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

you can use sync data api to send the data to wear apk, and notify the notification in wear apk, use setLocalOnly both phone and wear, so that you can get different notification to the phone and the android wear

Comment: This is correct answer, apart that I would suggest MessageAPI as it is faster and have all needed things for that work.